# Render list information in Masterpage sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have site information in a custom list that i need to expose on a Masterpage in SharePoint 2013.  I'm developing the masterpage using the design manager and I tried the Content Query Webpart from the snippets library but it renders a url to the List Item which I don't want.  I am just after the static content.

Does anyone know another way to render static list information to a SP2013 Masterpage? Or is there a better way of storing the site specific information that can be easily rendered in the Masterpage?

Originally in SP2010 i created a series of user controls that i added to the mastpage in a VS solution and deployed the feature.  I want to try and avoid this as we don't want to have to keep deploying a feature everytime there is a masterpage change.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the XSLT used by the Content By Query web part to display other columns from the list.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms497457(v=office.14).aspx

You might also consider using the Reusable Content list depending on your requirements.

See http://sharepointelement.com/2012/01/27/adding-reusable-content-within-master-pages/